# How to query Oracle via JDBC for an intersection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to check from Java if a certain user has at least one group membership. In Oracle (12 by the way) there is a big able that looks like this:

```
DocId  | Group
-----------------
    1  | Group-A
    1  | Group-E
    1  | Group-Z
    2  | Group-A
    3  | Group-B
    3  | Group-W
```

In Java I have this information:

```
docId = 1
listOfUsersGroups = { "Group-G", "Group-A", "Group-Of-Something-Totally-Different" }
```

I have seen solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527097/how-to-check-if-at-least-one-of-a-group-of-rows-has-a-specific-value), but this is not the approach I want to go for. I would like to do something like this (I know this is incorrect syntax) ...

```
SELECT * FROM PERMSTABLE WHERE DOCID = 1 AND ('Group-G', 'Group-A', 'Group-Of-Something-Totally-Different' ) HASATLEASTONE OF Group
```

... and not use any temporary SQL INSERTs. The outcome should be that after executing this query I know that my user has a match because he is member of `Group-A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (using IN condition):

```
SELECT * FROM PERMSTABLE WHERE DocId = 1 AND Group IN 
            ('Group-G', 'Group-A', 'Group-Of-Something-Totally-Different')
```

Comment: How would I set the content of `IN` using jdbc syntax ?

Comment: @Marged check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)